# Use sed to add a space before every line starting with a period, compatible with terminal colors

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, colors

Sample colored text (this is produced from ls):

```
\e[0m\e[01;34m.cache\e[0m/
\e[01;34minferno\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.JUNK\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.nano\e[0m/
\e[01;34mpoo\e[0m/
\e[01;34mPrograms\e[0m/
\e[01;34mrestore\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.ssh\e[0m/
\e[34;42mWorkspace\e[0m/
a.sh
.bash_history
\e[01;32m.bash_profile\e[0m*
.bashrc
gg dd.txt
```

Sed command that won't work:

```
sed -r 's/^((\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK])*[^\.])/ \1/'
```

I'm attempting to do this by echoing a variable containing the text and piping it into sed, like so:

```
 echo "$text" | sed -r 's/^((\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK])*[^\.])/ \1/'
```

I just want any line that does not start with a period to have a single space prepended before it. I've spent hours on this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want any line that does not start with a period to have a
>   single space prepended before it.

Update as per this comment:

> It should ignore colors. `\e[01;34m.nano\e[0m/` should not have a space
>   in front of it

Try **this** `sed`:

```
sed -E '/^\.|\\e/! s/(.)/ \1/'
```

Example:

```
echo "\e[0m\e[01;34m.cache\e[0m/
\e[01;34minferno\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.JUNK\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.nano\e[0m/
\e[01;34mpoo\e[0m/
\e[01;34mPrograms\e[0m/
\e[01;34mrestore\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.ssh\e[0m/
\e[34;42mWorkspace\e[0m/
a.sh
.bash_history
\e[01;32m.bash_profile\e[0m*
.bashrc
gg dd.txt" | sed -E '/^\.|\\e/! s/(.)/ \1/'
\e[0m\e[01;34m.cache\e[0m/
\e[01;34minferno\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.JUNK\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.nano\e[0m/
\e[01;34mpoo\e[0m/
\e[01;34mPrograms\e[0m/
\e[01;34mrestore\e[0m/
\e[01;34m.ssh\e[0m/
\e[34;42mWorkspace\e[0m/
 a.sh
.bash_history
\e[01;32m.bash_profile\e[0m*
.bashrc
 gg dd.txt
```

Only the lines that do **not** start with a dot (`.`), OR starts with a "color" (`\e`) has one space character in front.

Comment: It should ignore colors. `\e[01;34m.nano\e[0m/` should not have a space in front of it.

Comment: See my edit/update.